# Keyboard shortcut for building a specific project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How can I define a shortcut key to build the startup project in my solution?

I often build the default project so it is kind of frustrating to have to use the mouse to scroll to the right project in Solution Explorer, right click it and choose build project. There must be an easier way.

I have looked in to the option "Build.BuildSelection" but this only builds the project that the currently open file is located in. So if I have project A that has a reference to project B and I edit a file in project B, then this shortcut is not usable for me since it is project A I want to build.

With Visual Studio 2010 I could just create a macro to achieve what I want, but I haven't been able to make this work. I looked in to the option of creating a macro for Visual Studio 2015 but I got stuck and never received any answers to my question about this ([JavaScript macro for building the startup project in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944661)).

Building the entire solution is also not an option since some of the projects in the solution are set up to be built in other ways and either fails when Visual Studio tries to build them or just takes very long time to complete.

Comment: This could also be solved using a *Build Configuration* that only builds the projects you want.

Comment: Well, I guess this kinda works when I select the correct project and set a shortcut key to "Build Solution". I would have to select all the referenced projects though because it seems it can not automatically figure out if any changes have been made in referenced projects. Fortunately there is essentially only one so this is of course doable for me here, but I would still like a solution where I would get the same effect as right clicking on the project and selecting "Build". Drop an answer and if nothing better has turned up in a couple of days, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: You can run an old VB macro in VS 2015 with my Visual Commander extension https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Great success! Thank you for the tip! I tried it and it works like a charm! I posted an answer with the full description of how I made it work. Hope that's okay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Sergey Vlasov's extension [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) it is possible to use VB macros in Visual Studio 2015.

I created a macro with the following script and when running this macro, the startup project is built.

```
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class C

    Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand

    Sub Run(DTE As EnvDTE80.DTE2, package As Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package) Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand.Run

        DTE.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.Parent.Activate()
        Dim sb As SolutionBuild2 = DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild

        For i As Integer = 0 To sb.StartupProjects.Length - 1
            sb.BuildProject(sb.ActiveConfiguration.Name, sb.StartupProjects(i), True)
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```